# simpleMDE set value not parsing properly

Tags: javascript, simplemde

I'm using [simple markdown editor](https://github.com/sparksuite/simplemde-markdown-editor) this in my form like

````
<textarea id="editor-board">
<script>
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE({ element: $("#editor-area")[0] });

simplemde.value("# How are
**This is bold** This is normal
_This is italic_ This is normal
```
commands goes here
demo commands
sudo apt update
```");
````

But this is not even loading plugin in textarea.

Wherease, on setting value to be `value('this is simple text');` works fine.

**How to set the markdown syntax in the editor?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this using [ES6 Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();

simplemde.value(`# How are
  **This is bold** This is normal
  _This is italic_ This is normal
  \`\`\`
  commands goes here
  demo commands
  sudo apt update
  \`\`\`
`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><textarea rows="5" name="text"></textarea></p>
```

OR do something like this for ES5:

````js
var simplemde = new SimpleMDE();

simplemde.value("# How are\n  **This is bold** This is normal\n  _This is italic_ This is normal\n  ```\n  commands goes here\n  demo commands\n  sudo apt update\n  ```\n");
````

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/simplemde/latest/simplemde.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><textarea rows="5" name="text"></textarea></p>
```

Comment: But the main issue is that the contents to set are not fixed. They are dynamically coming from the database and I'm using a variable to print the string in the `value()` function. Above included string is what is saved in the database and I copied that from source view. **How to convert the string to what you have suggested?**

Comment: That is simple like `simplemde.value(\`${your_string_variable}\``, you will just need to escape the `\`` chars before calling this. You can search for that in SO. Many examples are present.

Comment: adding ` works for symbols other than code block. Adding a code block is not working.

Comment: as I said you will need to escape those like I have done in demo `\\`\\`\\``, but dynamically using regex, etc.